# Is there a method for counting 2nd degree ties in a network?

Tags: r, social-network

I have an excel file with an edgelist of 1st degree ties, and would like to get back an excel file with information about 2nd degree ties (count per person) in a social network. I would like to use R for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using the `igraph` package. First, since you provide no data, here is an example graph.

```
library(igraph)
EL = as.matrix(read.table(text="From  To
    2    5
    3    5
    1    6
    3    6
    3    7
    2    8
    4    8
    1    9
    4    9
    6    9
    7   10
    8   10",
header=TRUE))

g = graph_from_edgelist(EL, directed=FALSE)

set.seed(2020)
LO = layout_with_fr(g)
plot(g, layout=LO, margin=0)
```

[image: Example graph]

Now, to get exactly what you asked for, you can use the `ego_size` function.

```
ego_size(g, order=2)
 [1] 5 6 8 7 6 7 6 7 6 6
```

This gives the number of points at most two hops away from each node.

You can see what this is doing in more detail, by looking at *which nodes* are included. 
Just as an example, I will display which nodes are at most two hops away from node 7.

```
ego(g, order=2, nodes=7)
[1]  7  3 10  5  6  8
```

This matches the picture. Nodes 3 and 10 are next to node 7. Nodes 5 and 6 connect to node 3. Node 8 connects to node 10.